# Sencha touch list is not refreshing

Tags: list, sencha-touch-2

I am using 'list' as a child component on view. I am not using any store to get data, instead I'm using simple 'data' property of list to layout my list items.

My requirement is to update the same list with taping a button on the same view. I am updating data with the `setData` method of the list, but the new items are appended to the list instead of replacing old ones. Also the list is is not behaving well. Event listeners (`itemtap`) for the old data records seems to be intact.

This is view that contains the list http://jsfiddle.net/xer1es0w/
Here is the Controller using that view http://jsfiddle.net/6gwwes0p/

Note: I have truncated some lines of code for the reason of my code security

[image]

Comment: Please add some code so that we can check the problem.

Comment: @SujataChanda code is now included at end of the question.

Answer (score 2):

in your example you are not really doing what you think that you are doing.

Here is the code of what happends once you setData(bla).

```
function(data) {
    var store = this.getStore();
    if (!store) {
        this.setStore(Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            data: data,
            autoDestroy: true
        }));
    } else {
        store.add(data);
    }
}
```

Sencha looks if there is a store for the data. If not it creates one.

On your first run it adds a store and then it ADDS data to the store.

==> on the second run you need to call

```
list.getStore().removeAll();
list.addData(bla);
```

or try

```
list.getStore().setData(bla);
```